# Using wired LAN and wireless tethering network

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, wired

I have a PC connected to the LAN of my organization.

Now we have a issue with internet connection so I have activated tethering on my smartphone and connected my laptop to the wireless network of the smartphone.

I can access the network resourced through the wired LAN but I cannot access internet.

Is there a way to use network resources and internet at the same time using wired and wireless connection?

```
IPv4 Tabella route
===========================================================================
Route attive:
     Indirizzo rete             Mask          Gateway     Interfaccia Metrica
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.43.1    192.168.43.44     55
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.43.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.43.44    311
    192.168.43.44  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.43.44    311
   192.168.43.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.43.44    311
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.43.44    311
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.43.44    311
===========================================================================
```

192.168.96.0 is my wired network
192.168.43.0 is wireless network

Thank you

Comment: [route](http://ss64.com/nt/route.html) - Manipulate network routing tables. Route packets of network traffic from one subnet to another by modifying the route table.

Comment: thank you! I thought about routing table but I do not understand what to change ...

Comment: Be aware that in many organisations, what you want to do may violate internal IT security policies, and could have adverse consequences for you.

Answer (score 1):

[ForceBindIP](https://r1ch.net/projects/forcebindip) will allow you to chose which application uses which network interface

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](//meta.superuser.com/q/5329) paying particular attention to the items in **bold**. After doing so, please [edit your answer](//superuser.com/posts/1334969/edit) so it follows the guidelines.